# Get output of script without alternate screen in bash

Tags: linux, bash, output

I have a script that I can't edit that I call regularly via ssh. The script use an alternate screen (`tput rmcup`) to display the progress of the script and at the end switch back, and gives the results in output console.

I'm trying to automate the launch of that script and data collection but I can't find a way to collect in a variable or a file only the resulted output.

For example here's what I get as output in the console:

```
 SFTP:
Server   Result
S01      OK
S02      OK
```

But in the actual file:

```
^[[?1049h^[[22;0;0t^[[3J^[[H^[[2J^[[1;1H^[[3J^[[H^[[2J^[[1;1H
 FTP:
Server   Result
S01      Waiting
S02      Waiting
^[[?1049l^[[23;0;0t
 FTP:
Server   Result
S01      OK
S02      OK
```

I understand that it writes everything including the commands that update the screen since `cat "file.txt"` displays that file perfectly. But is there a way to get a parsed/clean output without changing the source script?

Comment: What's your question? Printing everything after the last screen control codes would seem to produce the final output, based on your example. (Though it seems to have FTP, not SFTP.)

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You seem to be asking for an existing tool (which is off-topic) or general guidance for getting started with basic learning about string processing tools (which is also off-topic). A simple `sed` or Awk script would probably work, but then a proper question would include your own efforts at writing one. If you are not there yet, read a basic tutorial for either of these tools. `sed` is more basic, and rather hard to read and write, but effective for simple tasks. Eventually, you should have at least a basic familiarity with both.

Comment: This may help https://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html

Comment: please update the question with your expected result; in order to obtain an exact copy of your file ... could you run `base64 file.txt` and post the output to your question (we can then use `base64 -d` to rebuild the file in our environment with the same exact control codes in the file)

Answer (score 0):

For what you have provided as output file (OUT.txt), I suggest you try the following:

```
tac OUT.txt | 
awk '{ print $0 ; if( $1 == "FTP:" ){ exit } ; }' |
tac
```

tac is like cat, but provides each line input in reverse order.